# How to work with C# Parallels instructions and Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, parallels

For example, I need to do a *Paralell.ForEach* and each interaction needs to do a *SaveT* from my Repository Architecture. The NHibernate Session is lost and a NHibernate Exception is thrown. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are not thread-safe (ISession).
Try to create several sessions with ISessionFactory.

Also, lock objects before they are attached to the session and Session.Evict() at the end of the session.